# Using $x^2 ≡ 36 \mod 101$, answer the following questions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem:

Using $x^2 ≡  36 \mod 101$, answer the following questions.

a) show that $101$ is a prime.

b) Use a) to find all solutions for modulo $101$.

I can't even start these questions.

for a), I kind of know that I have to use square root...

Comment: Can you solve $(x-6)(x+6)\equiv 0 \pmod{101}?$

Comment: Nope... but could you please tell me how did you get (x−6)(x+6) ? Thanks..

Comment: The same as for usual numbers, you know $36=6\times  6$ and the binomial formula
$(x-a)(x+a)=x^2-a^2$

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a somewhat naive approach to (a). To start, notice that $x^2 \equiv 36 \pmod{101}$ is the same as $x^2 - 36 \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$, and we can then factor this polynomial into $(x+6)(x-6) \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$. Now, notice that for $101$ to be prime, we require $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ to be an [integral domain](http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~john/MT4517/Lectures/L4.html) -- this just means that there are no zero divisors. So, in order for this to be an integral domain, we check that the only time when $(x+6)(x-6) \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$ is when $x = 6$ or $x = 95$. We can then check all of the numbers $\{0,...,100\}$ using a computer. For example, you can use Python and the following script:

`for i in range(101):
   if i != 6 and i != 95:
      if (i+6)*(i-6) % 101 == 0:
         print("Not an integral domain!")`

Running this, you see that it does not print the statement. So, $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, and so we have that $101$ is prime.

One can also prove this using contradiction. Assume that $101$ is not prime. This means that there exists an integer $x$ such that $101 | (x+6)(x-6)$ but $101 \nmid (x+6)$ and $101 \nmid (x-6)$. Hence, $101n + j = x+6$ and $101m + k = x-6$. Multiplying, we have $(101n+j)(101m+k) = 101^2nm + 101(nk+mj) + jk$. Hence, we have $jk = 0$ or $101 | jk$. If $jk = 0$, we have a contradiction, since this means $101 | (x+6)$ or $101 | (x-6)$ (since either j or k is 0). Notice that $m = n$ and $j = k + 12$ by our construction. Then this means that $101 | k(k+12) = k^2 + 12k$. Hence, $k^2 + 12k \equiv 0 \pmod{101}$, or $k^2 \equiv -12k \pmod{101}$. We see that $k = 0$ is a solution, but this gives us a contradiction since this means $101 | (x-6)$. We also see that $89$ is a solution (since $k \equiv -12 \pmod{101}$ implies $k = 101-12 = 89$). If $k = 89$, this gives us a contradiction as well, since this means $101 | (x+6)$. Since these are the only two solutions to $k^2 \equiv -12k \pmod{101}$, we have that this forces $101$ to be prime.

Personally, I like the first solution better than the second, but if it were a homework problem or if the numbers were more difficult, then the second approach is better.

Once you've established (a), (b) follows directly. Since it's prime, the only roots of the polynomial are $x = 6$ and $x=95$, and moreover those are the only solutions.